# AutoHotKey (AHK) How to make a gui that doesn't take over

Tags: user-interface, autohotkey

I'm trying to make a script that when I'm typing, I can press a button and a frameless window will pop up, i can select one of the options with the 1-3 keys, and it will take that text and put it where i was typing. How would I do this? I'm so far gotten a Gui to pop up, but when i press one of the keys, it doesn't send the text to where i was typing before.
Are there any tags that need to be added to the GUI code to make it so it doesn't take over as the active window, but will still take input on which button i press with?

```
^v::
if (num >= 1) {
    Gui, Add, Button, w200 gbutton1, &1. %var1%
}

Gui, Color, EEAA99
Gui, Add, Text, BackgroundTrans
Gui +LastFound +AlwaysOnTop +ToolWindow -Caption
WinSet, TransColor, EEAA99
Gui, Show, AutoSize Center
Return
```

Comment: you mean like Autocorrect or suggestions ??

Comment: I guess suggestions. Really all I want it to have a menu pop up above the cursor at the time, with a few options listed, and when I select one by pressing a number, it will insert that into the text. So far all I have is the window pop up, and when I press the number, it sends the text, but since the GUI is the active window, the text goes nowhere.

Comment: Oh use WinActivate? Show me the code

Comment: I can't figure out how to post with formatting kept in tact, so here you go http://pastebin.com/s8zv6qWV Thats a snippet of code I'm working with

Comment: okay. I have it figured out now. One last thing though, instead of using send to slowly print out text, is there a way to instantly send text?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  You can paste code simply; insert the text in the textarea, select the whole code region and click on the braces button above the text area; If you found the solution to your problem, it's best to provide that as an answer to your own question.

Comment: use SendInput or this custom function SendStr(str) {
 oldClipboard:=ClipboardAll
 Clipboard:=str
 Send {ctrl down}v{ctrl up}
 Clipboard:=oldclipboard
}

Answer (score 1):

You can show a GUI without activating it if you do not want the GUI to take focus.

```
Gui, Show, AutoSize Center NoActivate
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. :)
I just put "WinGetTitle, title, a" at the top before the GUI pops up, and "WinActivate [title]" after each command so it closes the gui and goes back to the window.